# Replace heroku link with MongoDb compass database

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I want to change heroku link with mongodb database (local / mongocompass)

this is the heroku link

```
axios
      .get("https://employee-management-fk-api.herokuapp.com/api/employee", {
        headers: {
          authorization: localStorage.getItem("token") || ""
        }
      })
```

the localdataabse (mongodb) is named humanman

Sorry if the question is for beginners but I did not found anything while searching
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just swap out an API endpoint for a direct database connection. This'll take some work.

Comment: As ceejayoz said, you can't connect to a database from a web client. You'll need to create an API on a server that connects to the database and serves that data to the client.